# The dimension of a point and how to construct it

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Wikipedia states:

> In mathematics, the dimension of a vector space V is the cardinality (i.e. the number of vectors) of a basis of V over its base field.

Furthermore about the dimension of a point

> The dimension of a vector space is the maximum size of a linearly independent subset. In a vector space consisting of a single point (which must be the zero vector 0), there is no linearly independent subset. The zero vector is not itself linearly independent, because there is a non trivial linear combination making it zero: $1 \cdot \mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$

**How would a mathmatician explain how to construct a point, for example $p_1=(1,2,3)\in \mathbb{R}^3$?**

I'm told this point has no dimensions, but then there has to be a space that constructs it, a vector space that is. And this space has to have some linearly independent subset, surely I can't construct it from the empty set. I don't know if I can even talk about a dimension of a point which is not zero, since it is no vector space.

Or are points just "there" devoid of any need to be constructed? Somewhere my thinking must be wrong, so clarification is appreciated.

Comment: You could see a point as an affine space with dimension $0$. Apart from that you don't need to «construct» the point. You said it is an element of ${\mathbb R}^3$, that is to say a cartesian product. The existence of the cartesian product is an axiom in set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "a space that constructs it"? That might be the source of your confusion.

$(1,2,3)\in \mathbb{R^3}$. If you want a vector space that has $(1,2,3)$ in it, that's a good answer. If you want to show someone that point, I would draw $\mathbb{R}^3$ and put a dot at the coordinates $(1,2,3)$.

If you want a vector space *generated* by $(1,2,3)$, you get a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ because you get all of its scalar multiples. As a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ this vector space would be $\{(x,y,z):6x=3y=2z\}$

---

Re: the dimension of $(1,2,3)$

There are several ways to measure dimension. $(1,2,3)$ has a *geometric* dimension of $0$ because it's a point, but in the sense of dimension that you quote it doesn't have dimension because it's not a vector space, and the *vector-space dimension* (which is what that definition is) is only defined for vector spaces.

The most common notion of geometric dimension (which is what we talk about when we say a triangle is 2D) comes from embedding geometric objects inside of vector spaces, and assigning them the dimension equal to the minimum $k$ such that they embed into $\mathbb{R}^k$. So a single point embed into the $0$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^0\cong\{0\}$ and therefore is zero dimensional. A line embeds into $\mathbb{R}^1$ but not into $\mathbb{R}^0$ and is therefore one dimensional. A triangle embeds into $\mathbb{R}^2$ but does not embed into $\mathbb{R}^1$ and is therefore two dimensional. Generalizing this definition out of geometry and into topology gives rise to the [Lebesgue Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension), also known as the topological dimension. The Lebesgue dimension agrees with the embedding dimension, but allows you to talk about the dimension of topological objects more generally.

Comment: I agree that was unclear. If I have a point $(1,2,3)$ and it is zero dimensional, the above definitions tell me ( I think ), that there are no linearly independent basis vectors needed to construct it. Construct it in the same manner as I can construct $\mathbb{R}^2$ with two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: No they don't, because you're quoting the definition of the dimension /of a vector space/. A point isn't a vector space. You'd have the same difficulty if you asked about a triangle. Triangles and points are geometric objects and have geometric dimension, which is different from vector space dimension.

Comment: What is the definition of a geometric dimension? Wikipedia and other sites mainly talk about other kinds of dimensions

Comment: @plsmakemedomath I elaborated in both sections of my answer.

Comment: The last paragraph really clarifies the concept, especially how the two seemingly different definitions of dimensions are related

Comment: @plsmakemedomath If this topic intrigues you, you might find fractal dimension interesting. For "common" shapes it gives the same answer as the embedding definition, but for fractals it doesn't. For fractales, it often gives fractional or irrational dimension: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension

Comment: I'll need to study a lot more to really dive into the topic, but it is very interesting nonetheless! Thank you very much

Comment: Any vector subespac of R^3 must contain the point {0,0,0}. So the only point that is a vector (sub)space in R^3 is (0,0,0).